# Does com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine API works in JRE 1.5?

Tags: java, java-5

I wants to attach with virtual machine with below way.

```
VirtualMachine localVirtualMachine = VirtualMachine.attach(PID);
          localVirtualMachine.loadAgent(agentName);
          localVirtualMachine.detach();
```

As per below link, it support from JRE 1.6. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html

Is there any other way to loadAgent in JRE 1.5?

Thanks,
Mahen

Comment: Java 5 is obsolete. It is over a decade old and was end of life years ago. Even when it was current, using com.sun was a big code smell. Upgrade.

Comment: Dear sir,My client is using the legacy system with jre 5 and below it.